# Code review for learning purposes

Tags: discussion

I just found this site (New to stack exchange in general), and I am working on teaching myself c#. Would it be acceptable to post working code for people to pick apart and suggest better ways of doing things, or is it more for acceptable practice rather than alternative methods?

I read the FAQ, and it would seem to fit, but wanted to make sure.

Comment: can you rephrase the last sentence; appears to me you are sort of saying the same thing... or it's just hard to read

Comment: Well, what I mean is that it fits the rules for the site, but I'm not sure it would fit the intent of the site. I've been a programmer for a long time, so my code is generally well formed. I've been working on learning c#, and I have a side project that I'm creating for that purpose. The code is generally well formed, works, and does the job. But, I don't know if there is a better way to accomplish something simply because I haven't learned it yet. So I wasn't sure about posting code for the purpose of "Tell me what I don't know".

Comment: I don't see that as a problem at all. In fact, you may be amazed at the suggestions you get.

Comment: Thanks. I already spotted one bad database design when I was considering which section to publish. :-/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the only questionable part from the [*I'm confused! What questions are on-topic for this site?* section of the FAQ](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/faq#im-confused-what-questions-are-on-topic-for-this-site) is the 3rd point:

> Is it actual code from a project rather then pseudo-code or example code?

A personal learning project is also a project, so I think it is ontopic on Code Review as well as, for example, [quick-sort](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quick-sort) and [homework](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework) questions.